# Give element in vector access to other elements

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

For context, I am creating a simple game engine.

My game objects are all stored in a vector and every frame each object is iterated over and updated.

The problem with this is that occasionally an object needs to have access to the data of other objects in the vector, I can't pass in an immutable/mutable reference to the vector itself because it is being iterated over mutably.

How can i allow each game object to access fields (position, rotation e.t.c.) of other game objects in the same Vector?

here is the loop that is causing issues:

```rust
for entity in self.scene.collidable_entitys {
    match &mut entity.value {
        Some(e) => {
            e.update(&frame_descriptor, &self.input, &self.scene.collidable_entitys);
            entity_count += 1;
        }
        None => {}
    }
}
```

the compiler doesn't like me giving an immutable reference to self.scene.collidable_entitys because it is borrowed mutably to iterate over.

here is a simple example to show my problem.

```rust
use std::vec::Vec;

struct Object {
    a: u32,
    b: u32,
}

impl Object {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            a: 0,
            b: 0,
        }
    }
    
    fn update(&mut self, objects: &Vec<Option<Object>>) {
        // mutate self here
        // but also read from the object vector
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    let mut vector: Vec<Option<Object>> = Vec::new();
    vector.push(Some(Object::new()));
    vector.push(Some(Object::new()));
    vector.push(Some(Object::new()));

    for obj in vector.as_ref() {
        match obj {
            Some(o) => o.update(&vector),
            None => {}
        }
    }
}
```

any help or alternatives to systems i could use is much appreciated.

Comment: something like this `entity.value.as_deref_mut().map(|e| ...` ?

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that clearly states your issue

Comment: @Zeppi if I understand you correctly, yoiu are saying to replace the match &mut entity.value and the block after it with entity.value.as_deref_mut().map(|e| . Unfortunately this doesn't work for me, my problem seems to be arriving from the fact that iterating through the vector takes ownership of the vector. I have tried to get around this by using .as_ref() on the vector, but unfortuantely then i get a strange "cannot infer type error" on my loop. I will update the original post with a MCVE.

Comment: ok @Sreyas i have updated my post with a simple example of the problkem i am having

Comment: This is one of the major problems that an entity component system (ECS) intends to solve. In practice, you are probably better off [adopting an ECS framework](https://arewegameyet.rs/ecosystem/ecs/) in your game engine.

Answer (score 1):

The `entity` is mutably borrowed, and then you are trying to borrow the entire collection of entities. That isn't allowed because the entity is now borrowed twice.

Usually–-especially in game engines––this problem is solved by employing the Entity-Component-System (ECS) pattern. It gets around the problem by working with handles to the entities instead of references. ECS is usually very fast and feels like the perfect fit for Rust because it completely eliminates complex borrowing interactions. There is a big list of [ECS crates here](https://arewegameyet.rs/ecosystem/ecs/).

If you didn't want to use ECS, you can still take the idea of using handles or ids instead of references. For example, using the vector index as a temporary id and borrowing in very short scopes, to pull out individual fields that you need.

```
// take a slice instead of Vec so that you can't accidentally change its size, 
// which could invalidate the given obj_index.
fn update_obj(obj_index: usize, objects: &mut [Option<Object>]) {
    let obj = objects[obj_index];
    // etc
}
```

Comment: out of curiosity how does ECS solve the issue? wouldn't the borrow checker still be doing the same thing?

Comment: for example how would you even go about mutating the world from a game object?

Comment: @theflamingtiger in ECS, there is no concept of doing anything "from" a game object. It isn't object oriented. You make changes from a system - e.g. a physics system, player input system etc.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is splitting the vector into slices:

```
use std::vec::Vec;

struct Object {
    a: u32,
    b: u32,
}

impl Object {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            a: 0,
            b: 0,
        }
    }
    
    // here you should probably change type of objects
    fn update<'a>(&'a mut self, objects: impl Iterator<Item = &'a Option<Object>>) {
        // mutate self here
        // but also read from the object vector
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    let mut vector: Vec<Option<Object>> = Vec::new();
    vector.push(Some(Object::new()));
    vector.push(Some(Object::new()));
    vector.push(Some(Object::new()));
    
    // 'i' is index of 'o'
    for i in 0..vector.len() {
        // here you split the vector into two mutable slices
        // (they have to be mutable because you need to get 'o' from them)
        let (objects_left_of_o, o_and_objects_right_of_o) = vector.split_at_mut(i);
        
        if let Some((Some(o), objects_right_of_o)) = o_and_objects_right_of_o.split_first_mut() {
            o.update(objects_left_of_o.iter().chain(objects_right_of_o.iter()));
        }
    }
}
```

Another solution is making use of interior mutability via `RefCell`.

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::ops::{Deref, DerefMut};
use std::vec::Vec;

struct Object {
    a: u32,
    b: u32,
}

impl Object {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self { a: 0, b: 0 }
    }

    // here you can't just borrow from every refcell, cause one of them should have already given
    // out the &mut self reference
    fn update(&mut self, objects: &Vec<RefCell<Option<Object>>>) {
        // DO NOT DO THIS
        for obj in objects {
            // if self refers to an element in the vector, this will PANIC because you would be trying to get another reference to self
            if let Some(o) = obj.borrow().deref() {}
        }

        // here maybe debug assert that you can't get borrow only one of the items (which is self)
        debug_assert_eq!(
            objects
                .iter()
                .filter(|refcell| refcell.try_borrow().is_err())
                .count(),
            1
        );

        for obj in objects {
            // if self refers to an element in the vector, this will PANIC
            if let Ok(reference) = obj.try_borrow() {
                if let Some(o) = reference.deref() {
                    // use 'o', which is an object different from self
                }
            }

            // alternatively, use let-Some-else instead of if-let-Some
            let Ok(reference) = obj.try_borrow() else { continue };
            let Some(o) = reference.deref() else { continue };

            // use 'o'...
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");

    // now the vector gets filled with a structure that wraps your Option<Object> and implements
    // interior mutability which means you push some checks onto runtime instead of compile time
    let mut vector = Vec::new();
    vector.push(RefCell::new(Some(Object::new())));
    vector.push(RefCell::new(Some(Object::new())));
    vector.push(RefCell::new(Some(Object::new())));

    // here you are looping on an immutable reference,
    // so you can reference the same vector later again
    for obj in &vector {
        // here obj is &RefCell<Option<Object>>

        // obj.borrow_mut() checks if it has already given out a mutable reference to Option<Object>
        // inside it. If it has it panics, if it hasn't it will return a RefMut<T> struct that
        // represents the borrow (which ends once the struct gets dropped)

        // RefMut<T>.deref_mut() dereferences RefMut<T> to &mut Option<Object>

        if let Some(o) = obj.borrow_mut().deref_mut() {
            // here 'o' is &mut Object, and because you haven't borrowed the vector mutably anywhere,
            // you can do an immutable borrow here
            o.update(&vector);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: wouldn't both of these solutions reduce performance significantly because you either need to do a lot of operations with vectors or have a ref cell for every object?

Comment: @theflamingtiger What about these solutions do you think will "reduce performance significantly"? "a lot of operations with vectors" are just a few bounds checks at worst, and "ref cell for every object" just means having one additional `isize` integer per object and a quick if check of that integer per `borrow_mut()`

Comment: As an extension to this, is it possible to get a mutable reference to the vector?

Comment: @theflamingtiger I mean.. anything is possible with `unsafe` code... but you're asking about safe rust, so no. Think about it, if you get a (mutable or immutable) reference to something inside the vector (`o` and `self` in `update` in your case) and then also get a mutable reference to that vector, you could call `vector.clear()` for example, making `o` / `self` point to **invalid memory**

Comment: But you could get an iterator over mutable references to the elements of the vector excluding `o`, in the first solution, just replace `impl Iterator<Item = &'a ...>` with `impl Iterator<Item = &'a mut ...>` and in `main` in `for` in `if let` replace the two `iter()`s with `iter_mut()`s