# How can I avoid nested vectors and self referencing structs?

Tags: rust, vector, data-structures, struct, reference

I have the following problem to which I would like to find a Rust-idiomatic solution.

The "step 0" of what I want to do is the following

```
struct Point {
    x: f32,
    y: f32
}

struct ElementMetadata{}
struct SuperElementMetadata{}

struct Element {
    metadata: ElementMetadata,
    points: Vec<Point>
}


struct SuperElement {
    metadata: SuperElementMetadata,
    elements: Vec<Element>
}
```

that is, I have a collection of `Point`s owned by `Element` and a collection of `Element`s owned by `SuperElemet`. However, for later performance reason, I would like to have all the `Point`s of the `SuperElement` in a contiguous buffer, so I was thinking to refactor the `SuperElement` like this:

```
struct SuperElement<'a> {
    metadata: SuperElementMetadata,
    elements: Vec<Element>,
    points: Vec<Points<'a>>
}
```

and I have to refactor `Element` struct as well. The idea would be to have something like

```
struct Element<'a> {
    metadata: ElementMetadata,
    points_ref: &'a[Point]
}
```

However this would be an example of "self referencing struct" which is rather difficult to tackle. In C++(20) I would have used `std::span` inside `Element` and implemented a suitable move constructor for `SuperElement`. However I do not want to simply translate from C++ to Rust. I would like to have some Rust idiomatic ideas to refactor my code. What do you suggest?

Comment: You can use `unsafe` code, or a self-referential structs library (the only sound being [`ouroboros`](https://docs.rs/ouroboros)).

Comment: Do you ever add elements?

Comment: The elements are added just at the beginning of the execution of the program. I'm rather a newcomer, could you provide me some sketch of what you say?

Comment: Sounds like a good problem candidate for an [entity component system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_component_system). Having contiguous memory over the same components is one of the main motivations of such a system. Examples here are [`bevy_ecs`](https://crates.io/crates/bevy_ecs) and [`specs`](https://crates.io/crates/specs). Although I don't know your usecase, so of course I am just guessing.

Comment: When you construct the `SuperElement`, do you know all elements ahead of time?

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75578548/give-element-in-vector-access-to-other-elements

Comment: In general for these types of problems: try to avoid references and lifetimes, and use array indices instead. Lifetimes do not work well with these kinds of structures.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman, yes they are know all at once when `SuperElement`  would be initialized.

Comment: @Finomnis. I was thinking in using indices instead of references.

Comment: [Here's an example using `ouroboros`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=70f58f79ec8383875ce4f01dc052e7b6) (doesn't work on the playground because no `ouroboros`).

Comment: What is missing from this question is an example of _how_ the buffer of points is used. Otherwise, there's a real risk of this being an X/Y problem. I'm almost certain that your real problem can be solved without self-referential structs, which will just make your solution more complicated and less idiomatic.

Comment: For example, if you have methods that need this data, you could pass the buffer as an argument. This pattern is _really_ common.

Comment: @PeterHall, the buffer of points is filled all at once with all the points and it is accessed `Element`wise then.